# Redraw issue when changing webkit-scrollbar width on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the width of a scrollbar on hover. I am able to change background color and other CSS properties, but width is fussy. If I right click the element and view the debug window -- a redraw occurs and I see a wider scrollbar. Is there a css-only solution to fixing this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/7j2H2/17/

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Custom Webkit Scrollbar */
/* http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
}

div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar,
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-button,
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece,
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    width: 40px !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #efefef;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

Comment: Because the content is not overflown? I added larger content into your `<div>` and the hover behavior seems to work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/7j2H2/18/

Comment: But I have overflow-y: scroll on the element? I don't understand why there needs to be content inside of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change event to the "hover of the scrollbar"

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3ZR/1/)</kbd>

Comment: `webkit` should never work in Chrome. It's Safari technology.

Comment: of course it does. Check this: https://codepen.io/MathieuRichard/pen/HAgnm