# Change scrollbar width/color on hover?

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a modified scroll bar:

```
       ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    visibility:hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#7c7c7c; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

I want to make it so that when I hover over it, the color will change from a light black to black and the width will increase by a few pixels smoothly. Preferably, I would like to be able to do this all through CSS but I'm guessing that's not possible so whatever gets the job done is much appreciated. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/kZ3ZR/1/ from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039303/redraw-issue-when-changing-webkit-scrollbar-width-on-hover

Comment: That seems to effect the entire scrollbar including the track. I was looking to make just the thumb expand a couple pixels

Comment: I guess you might have to go with dynamic/custom scrollbars such as http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Comment: Why you want to edit it with `-webkit-` prefix only. Its not supported for all browsers. Some plugin can help you. Maybe this one: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html Its very easy for styling.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Add this code and check.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background:black; 
}
```

Comment: Works for color but doesn't do anything when I set the width as 16px

Comment: How to change the width?