# Change width of scrollbar on hovering over it

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I am changing the css of scroll bar on hover, so whenever a user is over a scroll bar(not on div) the width of scroll should come to normal.

```
  width: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
  width: 50px;
  background:rgb(204 204 204 / 1);
}
```

I have tried this, but seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

look at this question:
[Redraw issue when changing webkit-scrollbar width on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039303/redraw-issue-when-changing-webkit-scrollbar-width-on-hover)

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Custom Webkit Scrollbar */
/* http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/ */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
div:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    width: 40px;
    /*background-color: red !important;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    /*background-color: #efefef;*/
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    /*background-color: #666;*/
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" /></div>
```

Comment: Not really. As you see in the demo , the width not always necessarily change when i am on the scroll. If my mouse cursor is over the scroll(thumb or track) the width should change.

Comment: This does not show how to widen the scrollbar on hover